# SELECT em duas tabelas diferentes com variáveis de mesmo nome

Tags: php, sql, select, join, inner-join

Tenho a seguinte consulta a ser feita:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT
        andamento_processual.licenciamento_cod,  
        andamento_processual.inter_simplificada_cod, 
        andamento_processual.inter_pretendida_cod, 
        andamento_processual.processo_numero,
        andamento_processual.processo_situacao,
        licenciamento.licenciamento_empreendimento_nome,
        empreendimento.empreendedor_nome_empreendimento,
        intervencao_amb_pretendida.inter_pretendida_cod,
        intervencao_amb_pretendida.intervencao_nome_empreendedor, <---
        intervencao_amb_simplificada.inter_simplificada_cod,
        intervencao_amb_simplificada.intervencao_nome_empreendedor <----
        FROM 
        andamento_processual 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN licenciamento ON andamento_processual.licenciamento_cod = licenciamento.licenciamento_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN empreendimento ON licenciamento.licenciamento_empreendimento_cod = empreendimento.empreendimento_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN intervencao_amb_pretendida ON andamento_processual.inter_pretendida_cod = intervencao_amb_pretendida.inter_pretendida_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN intervencao_amb_simplificada ON andamento_processual.inter_simplificada_cod= intervencao_amb_simplificada.inter_simplificada_cod
        WHERE 
        andamento_processual.processo_numero";
```

Meu problema é que existem duas variáveis de mesmo nome só que em tabelas diferentes, coloquei uma setinha apontando para elas. Quando coloco para exibir na tabela, só mostram os resultados da "intervencao_amb_simplificada.intervencao_nome_empreendedor".

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, dentro do WHILE:

```
if($inter_simplificada_cod){

        $nomeSimplEmpreendedor = $row['intervencao_nome_empreendedor'];

      }else if($inter_pretendida_cod){

        $nomePretEmpreendedor = $row['intervencao_nome_empreendedor'];

      }
```

Mas não funcionou! Tem como eu resolver isso sem trocar o nome da variável nas duas tabelas?

Comment: Posso estar com a vista meio ruim mas as linhas que você apontou tem o mesmo nome de campo mas são de tabelas diferentes.

Comment: é porque uma variável esta salva na tabela "intervencao_amb_pretendida" e outra na "intervencao_amb_simplificada", eu coloquei banco, mas são tabelas. Estava errado, arrumei aqui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar um alias no segundo nome para poder retorná-lo:

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT
        andamento_processual.licenciamento_cod,  
        andamento_processual.inter_simplificada_cod, 
        andamento_processual.inter_pretendida_cod, 
        andamento_processual.processo_numero,
        andamento_processual.processo_situacao,
        licenciamento.licenciamento_empreendimento_nome,
        empreendimento.empreendedor_nome_empreendimento,
        intervencao_amb_pretendida.inter_pretendida_cod,
        -- abaixo, mudando o nome utilizando 'as' 
        intervencao_amb_pretendida.intervencao_nome_empreendedor as intervencao_nome_empreendedor_pretendida, 
        intervencao_amb_simplificada.inter_simplificada_cod,
        -- abaixo mudando o nome sem usar o 'as'
        intervencao_amb_simplificada.intervencao_nome_empreendedor intervencao_nome_empreendedor_simplificada
    FROM 
        andamento_processual 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN licenciamento ON andamento_processual.licenciamento_cod = licenciamento.licenciamento_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN empreendimento ON licenciamento.licenciamento_empreendimento_cod = empreendimento.empreendimento_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN intervencao_amb_pretendida ON andamento_processual.inter_pretendida_cod = intervencao_amb_pretendida.inter_pretendida_cod
        LEFT OUTER JOIN intervencao_amb_simplificada ON andamento_processual.inter_simplificada_cod= intervencao_amb_simplificada.inter_simplificada_cod
    WHERE 
        andamento_processual.processo_numero
```

Com isso, você irá receber no resultset de retorno ambas os valores.

Comment: FUNCIONOU, não sabia que dava pra fazer assim. MUITO OBRIGADO!